# Visual Studio Online fatal: https://XX.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/MyProj/info/refs not found:

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I have created a Team project on Visual-Studio Online and I ran,

```
git clone https://XX.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/MyProj
```

Then I am getting,

```
fatal: https://XX.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/MyProj/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. I needed to select Git during creating Team Project instead of TFS

Comment: Not really, i just experience this problem and my repo on VSO is GIT, still finding the solution.